# How to plot multiple y values with a same x value?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

How can I plot this set of data on Excel or OriginLab, possibly scatter plot, where a same x value corresponds to multiple y

x, y

1, 1

1, 2

1, 3

2, 2

2, 3

2, 4

I actually have hundreds of x values, each with 20 different y values.

---

I found the reason. We need to make sure the number is on the right of the cell, not on the left.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite easily using Excel. First arrange your data like this:

[image]

Select all your data by holding and dragging the mouse over the cells containing the data as shown in the above picture. Now go to `Insert`>`Scatter`:

[image]

*(choose the type of scatter graph you want)*

That's it. You will have your graph right on the table. See this:

[image]

*(You can change axis name, scale and much more as per your requirements by going to
`Chart Tools`)*

I hope that this helped :)

Comment: Okay. You've done it now. If the answer deserve an upvote, please consider :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Actually, it is the format that makes the difference. I updated in my question.